# Change default folder color in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: directory, colors

Is there any way to change the default folder color in Ubuntu? It has always been orange, a color that I personally can't stand, and the only solution I have found is to manually change the color of each folder using Folder Color. But this is tedious to do if I need to copy many folders from a flash drive to my computer. Is there any way to tell Ubuntu that I want all the new folders to be blue instead of orange?

Comment: You can always install different icon sets which have blue colored folder icons. I personally use https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme everywhere.

Comment: https://www.fossmint.com/best-linux-icon-themes/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global color of your folder icons is determined by the icon theme you are using. By default, Ubuntu uses its own "Humanity" icon theme. You can install other icon themes on your Ubuntu installation, and apply these icon themes using Gnome Tweaks, Appearance tab. Gnome Tweaks is not installed by default: you can install it from Software Center.

How you install icon themes depends. Some icon themes are available in the Ubuntu Software center. For some themes, it suffices to extract the downloaded archive into a hidden .themes folder in your home directory. Other themes come as a .deb file.